# What happens if I interrupt or cancel `pg_upgradecluster`?

Tags: postgresql

I'm upgrading a PostgreSQL 9.5 cluster to 9.6 using `pg_upgradecluster`. It's taking an awful lot of time, so I'd like to cancel the process, delete unneeded databases, and start again. What are the risks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, [`pg_upgradecluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html) doesn't use `pg_upgrade`. It's creating a logical dump with `pg_dump` and restoring it (with `pg_restore`) on the new cluster.

To avoid this and speed up the process, you need to add the `-m upgrade` option.
If you need to speed up the process once more, you can add the `--link` so that the upgarde will be inplace. Be carefull, you can't cancel the process if you did it or you will loose your cluster.

If you didn't use the `-m upgrade` option and the `--link` option, you can cancel the process, drop the new cluster and create it again:

```
pg_dropcluster 9.6 <cluster_name>
pg_createcluster 9.6 <cluster_name>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I eventually did cancel the process (not using `-m upgrade` or `--link`, thankfully) and found one gotcha: it totally hosed the `pg_hba.conf` for both the old and new server (I guess it was locking things down for the duration of the upgrade?) It backs it up to `pg_hba.conf.pg_upgradecluster` though.